# multiple executions when bind click event on * selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension. In *content.js*, the one that interacts with the web pages, I bind a click event to all elements.

Google official documents say that whatever in *content.js* will just perform like the normal js file in web pages or applications. Since I am not familiar with jQuery, maybe there should be problems when bind event to all elements. Here is the code I used.

```
$(function () {

    $('*').on('click',function (event) {

    console.log("clicked");

    });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: May be you need [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: you are right! it works when I add this. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be binding a click event to every element on the page, that's pretty bad practice.

Instead, by `event-delegation` you can attach a click handler to the body, to act on all elements;

```
$('body').on('click', '*', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // do some stuff
});
```

Combining this with `e.stopPropagation()` will ensure the click event will only be fired once. You can access the element that was actually clicked with `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: Good point but if click event propagation is already stopped on original page (here OP is looking for chrome extension), it won't be fired for all elements. If i have really to deal with this, i'd capture event instead: `document.addEventListener('click', function(e){ console.log(e.target);}, true);` This would work even if click bubble is stopped and even for any dynamic elements

Comment: I tried both of your solutions and they both work well. thanks!